# Bootstrap collapse in tables - problems with borders and padding

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-tables

I got a table with another table in it. This has a div around with the collapse class from bootstrap. So i can collapse it with the button in the first row.

The problem ist as follow:

1. I want only the red border, when it is active. The black one should disappear. Is it possible without js?
2. Do I need to adjust the padding by myself, that each cell is among each other? Or is there another solution for that?
3. Would you do it the same way?

I have tried some other solutions, like changing the position of the div or without the td, but most of the time, the collapse is broken afterwards.

[image]

```css
table {
  width: 800px;
}

tr {
  background-color: darkgray;
}

td {
  padding:10px;
}

.tr-info {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.mybutton {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  font-size: 2px;
}

.hiddenRow {
  padding: 0;
}

.hiddenRow th {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Your Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css" media="screen" />


</head>

<body style="background: light-grey;">

  <div class="container mt-5">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="tr-info">
              <td>
                som1
              </td>
              <td>
                some2
              </td>
              <td>
                <button class="mybutton" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dodo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                                    Button with data-target
                                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" class="hiddenRow">
                <div class="collapse" id="dodo">
                  <table>
                    <thead>
                      <tr class="tr-info">
                        <th>dodo</th>
                        <th>dodo2</th>
                        <th>status</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr class="tr-info">
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>

              </td>

            </tr>
            <tr class="tr-info">
              <td>dodo</td>
              <td>d</td>
              <td>d</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi _ @Dominic Meyer check change

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I want only a bottom border and not for ever tr, so this is why i made a own class for that.

Comment: okay  _ @Dominic Meyer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

```
td ,th{
  min-width: 110px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

For align the table

For border

```
div#dodo {
    margin-top: -1px;
    z-index: 111;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Which border do you want to hide?

Comment: cheers, when you click on the button you see a black one over the red one. only the red should be there

Comment: In that case you need `JS`. On button `click` add class to its `parent` and then remove that `border` by css or directly apply css by `js`

Comment: okidoki thanks 4 the inputs :) and would you do it the same way? I mean the whole thing.

Comment: Means you need to me to remove that border too? by js?

Comment: @DominicMeyer updated my ans. By Css you can do that Cheers! if you got solution :)